# I have an entertaining "stuck file" issue

Tags: php, file, upload, delete-file, corrupt

I'm in the process of creating a simple image admin tool that allows users to upload and delete images from a server. So far it's very basic stuff. I discovered that uploading files whose file name includes a blank space causes a problem - everything in the name up to the space is included in the uploaded file name, but nothing past that. The problem with this isn't so much broken image links (I can deal with those), but the images can't be deleted using my delete tool or the simplest "unlink" script. Once I discovered the problem and the cause, I contacted our support people and they cleared out the two problem files. Unfortunately, because of system constraints here at work, I don't have FTP access.

Now you'd think it's all resolved, but no. I added very clear warning messages - in bold red text - onto this prototype admin tool, and I let my boss and a few others know of the tool by email, explaining CLEARLY that file names with spaces don't work. So... what does my boss do? She uploaded two files with blanks in the file name.

So until I have a way to add an idiot filter into the script, can anyone suggest how I might be able to delete these two files? I'd even be willing to delete the populated directory and recreate it (none of the images there mean anything, just random stuff).

And if there's no advice about getting these things unstuck, is there any advice as to how I might prevent my boss from acting like a moron, short of cutting off her fingers?

Comment: Why cant you validate your input to make sure that there are no spaces before you upload the file?

Comment: Convert the spaces to underscores?

Comment: Cutting off your boss's fingers sounds like the best option here!

Comment: For future knowledge, always recreate and rename the images as they are uploaded (using GD or some other image library) and delete the original files or you are going to have a lot worse problems then that in the future (security wise). Incidentally, this will solve your 'space in the filename issue' as well

Answer (score 2):

my best answer would be, as you said, move all other files to another folder, delete folder, recreate folder.
After that, I'm thinking you need urlencode in your php to deal with weird characters and spaces in filenames.
One question that might help others, are you in Linux or Windows?

As a test, until it's working, try writing to a drive that you have access to so you can play until it works. Then switch to the live system. This way you don't have to call support to delete your tests.

Also, you could just substitute all spaces for underscores as a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

While deleting files using `unlink()` with their names having spaces in them, escape the spaces with "\". This will only work on Linux.